# Can't add user in django-admin in an openshift hosted website

Tags: python, django, django-admin, openshift

I have django powered website that is hosted on openshift and I can't add users from the admin panel it ends up with this message:

Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value:
auth_user.last_login may not be NULL

I am not using any custom user model and my app was working locally

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should clean previous migrations. Rebuild migrations from the fresh copy of the model using the following:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

Then migrate it:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

For app specific migrations, add app name by the end of each command like this:

```
python manage.py makemigrations app
python manage.py migrate app
```

Comment: I have deleted the migration directory and add the migration commands in the action hooks, it didn't work. I can, however, edit the admin account

Comment: Try to edit the migration of user model and add `null = True` attribute to `last_login` column. Though that's not a good idea.